# ASP.NET Identity and Claims

Tags: asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity

I am trying to move away from WebForms and learn MVC, specifically using the new ASP.NET Identity model. However, I cant seem to find any formal documentation from Microsoft, that demonstrates how to create a claims object, and store it in a database for a authenticated user.

My site, needs to do the following:

1. Authentication a user - TICK
2. Create a Claim, and store user information in it, so that I can use it throughout the session - NO TICK
3. Pull back the users roles from the new ASP.NET Roles table - NOT TICK

Can anyone shed any light on how this can be achieve?

Comment: A great explanation of Claims and Identity for .NET Core : https://andrewlock.net/introduction-to-authentication-with-asp-net-core/ (not mine)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Honestly, I'm still learning the ropes with Identity, myself. Admittedly, the Microsoft provided documentation could be better, but I've never found any of their documentation all that helpful. The best stuff always comes from the community, and unfortunately, Identity is still so new that the community has had time to really flesh it out yet.

That said, here's what I know, with the understanding that there may be better ways that I'm simply not aware of, yet.

## Claims

Your `UserManager` has three methods of significance: `GetClaimsAsync`, `AddClaimAsync` and `RemoveClaimAsync`.

To get all claims for a user:

```
var claims = await UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(userId);
```

You can get the current user's id with:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Once you have the claims, to pull out a specific one:

```
var someClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "SomeClaimType");
```

Where "SomeClaimType" is the name of the claim as it was added. In some scenarios this might be a fully qualified URN, or it may just be a simple string. If it's not something you personally added, the best thing to do is just inspect the `claims` variable during a debug session to see what you actually have there.

Also, since the list of claims is a queryable, you can pretty much do whatever LINQ query you want on it, `Where`, `Count`, etc.

To add a new claim:

```
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new Claim("SomeClaimType", claimValue));
```

And to remove a claim:

```
await UserManager.RemoveClaimAsync(userId, someClaim);
```

## Roles

Roles work in a similar way. To get all roles for a user:

```
var roles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(userId);
```

To see if a user is in a particular role:

```
var hasRole = await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(userId, "SomeRole");
```

To add a user to a particular role:

```
await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(userId, "SomeRole");
```

And to remove:

```
await UserManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(userId, "SomeRole");
```

Adding the roles in the first place is a bit different; you have to create an instance of `RoleStore`.

```
var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
```

Then, you can use that to manage all roles. For example, to create a new role:

```
await roleStore.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("RoleName"));
```

To remove:

```
var identityRole = await roleStore.FindByNameAsync("RoleName");
await roleStore.DeleteAsync(identityRole);
```

Getting *all* roles, is not possible with the Identity-specific API at this time, but you can always fall back to querying with Entity Framework directly:

```
var allRoles = context.Roles.OrderBy(o => o.Name);
```

Comment: wow, thanks Chris. Is my assumption, that you create a claim once the user is authenticated. I treating it, correctly/incorrectly as some form of session / passport for that user. So, user login is successful, build up a Claim based on their settings, which I'd need to get from the database. Or am I way off?

Comment: Sort of. Claims are persistent, so this isn't something you need to build on each login. Claims are best seen as a way to store transient information that either may not apply to every user or otherwise isn't appropriate to actually go on the user table. Storing a Facebook auth token would be a good example of proper use of claims. But, in this scenario, once the user has logged in with Facebook and you've saved the claim, you can get their auth token from the claim any time. You don't have to keep adding it.

Comment: I'm looking for reliable documentation for whole week but I think AspNet.Identity documentation is pretty weak :| As a conclusion I understood that from your reply: "we should manage claims by ourselves" `await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new Claim("SomeClaimType", claimValue));` should be called for storing claims in database right? Because `context.Identity.AddClaim()` method has no effect to database.

Comment: Why didn't I find this post sooner? You've helped me finger something out that's been kicking me for weeks.

Comment: Right on target, Thanks for sharing this but i have a litlle silly question, we have to store the list of claims (that exist in system) ourselves ? Or identity provides some mechanism like roles e.g `AspNetRoles` table stores them and `AspNetUserRoles` has the mappings. 
TLDR is there any table like AspNetClaims ? I know there is a table `AspNetUserClaims` which will store claims of users.

Comment: @AliUmair: AspNetUserClaims is the table. Claims don't mean anything on their own (unlike roles), so you won't find something like AspNetClaims. They only exist in association with a user.

Comment: Yea I understand that, but my scenario is some users will have same claims like `ApprovePurchaseOrder` , `ApproveSalesOrder` , `Refund` etc. Now I don't wanna hardcord these strings so I guess i have to store them myself somewhere and assign these `Claims` whenever user is created and then validate user actions based on these.

Comment: Well, you would only need to "hard-code" them once. You can put them in a static class and then just reference them strongly-typed everywhere else.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding Asp.Net Identity, I would strongly recommend Brock Allen's implementation, called 'Identity Reboot'. Identity Reboot basically is a set of extensions to the ASP.NET Identity. It was inspired due to frustrations with the ASP.NET Identity implementation.

You can read an introductory article [here](http://brockallen.com/2014/02/11/introducing-identityreboot/).  You can download source code and samples from github [here](http://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.IdentityReboot).

You can install it using nuget:

```
www.nuget.org/packages/BrockAllen.IdentityReboot/
www.nuget.org/packages/BrockAllen.IdentityReboot.Ef/   (for entity framework)
```